# jQuery's ajax and duplication of divs after $.post() request to itself

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a little problem with jQuery. I have a PHP file where I have pagination to my 
list. This file has a script like this:

```
    <script>
    <?php if(isset($string)){ ?> var str = "<?php echo $string; ?>"; <?php } ?>
    var off = "<?php echo $offset; ?>";
    var npp = "<?php echo $num_per_page; ?>";

    $('a[id=pagination]').click( function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.get($(this).attr('href'),<?php if(isset($string)){ ?> { st : str },<?php } ?> function (data){ $('#pagination').empty(); $('#pagination').hide().html(data).fadeIn(); });
    });
    </script>
```

Content from this file is added with ajax method to div in a page after this page is loaded.
Script in that content is after `#pagination` div (who also belongs to this content).

Problem is, that after clicking a link, script is creating another `#pagination` div in first `#pagination` div, and everything working good on that second copy. Why this is happen and how I can to fix this, cause I don't want to have nested divs like that?

Comment: For a client-side question like yours do you really have to post server-side code? Give us what your browser sees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because the AJAX server is returning HTML that contains the `#pagination` DIV, and you're using `$("#pagination").html()` to put that inside the existing DIV with that ID.

You have several choices:

1. Change the server script so it returns just the contents, not the `#pagination` DIV.
2. Add a container DIV around `#pagination`, e.g. `#paginationContainer`, and use `$("#paginationContainer").html(data)`.
3. Use `replaceWith` instead of `html`, so you overwrite the whole DIV instead of the contents.

BTW, you don't need to use `.empty()` before you use `.html()`, since the latter completely replaces the contents.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried load just the content, but it was just added loaded content to older, but with third point of your reply everything work's just fine ;) Thanks!